# Python going with argv or *arg?

Tags: python, arguments, argv

If using `sys.argv` would there be any reason to use the `*arg` or would `sys.argv` be able to do everything that `*arg` would?

For instance:

```
>>>def test(*arg):
>>>    return arg
>>>
>>>print test('hello','salut','hola')
>>>('hello','salut','hola')
```

When I use `sys.argv` inside a file called `trial.py` that I call from the command-line:

```
import sys
def test(argument):
    return argument

print test(sys.argv[1])


python trial.py 'hello','salut','hola'
hello,salut,hola
```

Or is `argv` really geared to receiving just one argument and is it possible for argv to have more than 2 `items(argv[0],argv[1])`?

Comment: `->` http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv `<-`

Comment: I don't understand this question. In the case where you're calling `python trial.py 'hello','salut','hola'`, you're not calling it with three arguments, you're calling it with a single argument separated with commas, which is unusual to say the least.

Comment: You're confusing two completely different things. For starters, `*arg` isn't a variable. It's a command that means "unpack the contents of the variable `arg`. You could just as easily do `*foo` or `*bar`.

Comment: @JoelCornett I realize I could use *anything here for the name of the variable and the `*` would unpack it.  What I was wondering is when using the argv it seems to take multiple arguments aswell.

Comment: @tijko: `sys.argv` does not take any arguments. It's not a function. It's merely a list of strings. What happens is when you execute a script, python places all the command line arguments following the name of your script into a list. You can unpack this list like so (if you want) `_, first_arg, second_arg = sys.argv`, or you can unpack them as an argument to a function, e.g. `test(*sys.argv)`.

Comment: @Joel Cornett your explanation about sys.argv was really helpful.  I wasn't thinking of it as `[script.py, first, second, third].  If you read my comments below, I was putting in quotes and commas that was making it one long string too :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list containing all the arguments your python script was invoked with on the command line, with the script itself considered to be "argument 0".

It's an ordinary variable, same as any other variable that happens to contain a list. So there is no "choice" between `sys.argv` and `*arg`. `*arg` is syntax used for unpacking a list (or other sequence) to pass as multiple arguments to a call. You can use this syntax when passing `sys.argv`, as you can with any other variable containing a list. Or you can leave off the `*` and pass the whole list as one argument. Again, whether the list happens to be `sys.argv` is irrelevant to what happens.

I think the source of your confusion is that the shell from which you're invoking your python script doesn't consider multiple arguments to be separated the same way Python does. In Python, you separate multiple arguments with commas, so `'hello','salut','hola'` would be 3 arguments (although it would be more usual style to put spaces after the commas).

In most shells OTOH, arguments are separated by whitespace. `'hello','salut','hola'` does not contain any white space, so it's just **one** argument. So it shows up in the Python list in `sys.argv` as one item. Nothing magic has happened to concatenate multiple arguments into one for you; it's just that there only ever was one argument. The way to get the Python-level `sys.argv` to have 3 items would be to invoke your script like this:

```
python trial.py 'hello' 'salut' 'hola'
```

It also looks like you're using quotes in the shell command line the way you would in Python. In most shells, you don't always need to quote strings because everything is a string. Instead, quotes are used to tell the shell that a string containing whitespace is actually one argument with whitespace in it, rather than multiple arguments, or to disable certain special processing that shells do by default everywhere.

In Python `'hello'` is necessary to make the string "hello", so that Python doesn't try to read it as a variable `hello`. But in shells, `'hello'` and `hello` are both identical, and just mean the string "hello". But it would also be possible to write `he'll'o` with only a part of the string quoted. This just changes how the shell processes whitespace and other special characters inside the quotes, but still results in the same string "hello". This is why the shell is interpreting your form `'hello','salut','hola'` as the string "hello,salut,hola". There's no whitespace outside the quotes, so the 3 words doesn't get treated as separate arguments, and after doing their job of telling the shell how to process special characters the quotes just disappear.

Comment: this was a great summary, really hit the nail on the head.  Do you know why `[hi, salut, hola]` works but, not `(hi, salut, hola)`?

Comment: Depends on the context where you're using it. `[hi, salut, hola]` is a list of 3 items (assuming the variables are defined). `(hi, salut, hola)` is a tuple of 3 items (unless it's a call, like `some_func(hi, salut, hola)`, but on its own without something before it it's a tuple). Many things you can do with a list you can also do with a tuple, but not everything; `[hi, salut, hola]` and `(hi, salut, hola)` aren't supposed to do the same thing, and you shouldn't think of them as the same.

Comment: I understand datatypes, its the fact that a list could be passed and a tuple could not, well its the bracket character being passed not the parenthesis.  I made a separate post for this, turns out it is a BASH thing.  The parenthesis are BASH operators.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you meant you were using them in Python, rather than in the Bash command to invoke Python. Either form is a bit unusual in Bash. What actual argument values were you trying to pass to your script?

Comment: Well this all stemmed from me misunderstanding their usage.  So, there wasn't too much context for an actual task or need, just me trying them out in random test examples.  I got a few responses with this post saying this was all very odd, I should have explained that this more of me clearing up what their capabilities are.

Answer (score 4):

[sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) is a list of strings that contains any possible command line arguments supplied to a script.

The first element will be the name of the script itself, the rest of the entries will correspond to the items specified when the command was invoked via the command line. So to answer your last question, `argv` can contain more than 2 items.

e.g., if you had a script named `testme.py` and started it with

```
testme.py this is a test
```

then

```
sys.argv[0] would contain "test.me"
sys.argv[1] would contain "this"
sys.argv[2] would contain "is"
sys.argv[3] would contain "a"
sys.argv[4] would contain "test"
```

The shell will determine what entries get assigned to `sys.argv` - in your case since it was *one* continuous string without whitepace spearating parts, it was considered one argument (and hence appeared to have been concatenated).

Comment: so it would be possible to build up that list to include more than the script itself and the next entry?  I was finding that the arguments would be concatenated to a string, for the argv[1].

Comment: It is "built up" by default, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the arguments are not concatenated, each of them becomes a separate entry in the list of strings (that is `sys.argv`). The list is populated (built-up) automatically for you without any action required by you (once you supply the arguments on the command line), and you can access the information. Did this answer your question?

Comment: @Levon alright so, I was using commas parenthesis to separate each argument and I was getting one long string back.  `'this','is','a'` would return `this,is,a` all concatenated.  This was the reason I was thinking that there is only two items in the list and the second was just concatenated.

Comment: @tijko Look at the way the post calls the script and the way this answer does. They are *two different things*. The shell rules define how it breaks up the arguments. In this case, since there *is no white-space* it is parsed as a single token (or "parameter") *by the shell*. Different shells will act slightly differently, and Python will play games in windows to get cmd.exe to "work as expect".

Comment: tijko @pst is right with both of the comment made (immediately above and also in response to your original post)

Comment: @pst I saw it right as you were answering, thanks for helping and explaining that